# Is Dreamspark Windows iso the same as normal Microsoft Windows iso?

Tags: windows, iso-image, dreamspark

I can get Windows isos and keys by dreamspark. But are the iso the same ? If I use the iso from dreamspark for the pc of my family **but with a different key** will I be right ?

Sorry for my english and thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

From their site [FAQ](https://www.dreamspark.com/Support/FAQ/Default.aspx#asi14) section

**What’s the difference between the Microsoft software on DreamSpark and the Microsoft products I can buy in the store?**

*Nothing! DreamSpark offers the same completely loaded Microsoft software that professional developers pay good cash to purchase. However, through DreamSpark, we’re providing this software directly to students like you at no charge, to advance your learning and skills through technical design, technology, math, science and engineering activities. We want to give you the chance to explore the software tools used in business today to help prepare you to be a member of the next generation of developers.*

Through dreamspark you can get

- Windows Vista Business
- Windows 7 Professional
- Windows 8 Pro
- Windows 8.1 Pro

And they are the same as commercial versions of Windows. But if you have one key for one Windows, you can not enter the same key for another one!
*Also you **cannot** enter a key for Windows 7 Proffesional to a Windows 7 Ultimate. (you must have key for that version of Windwos)*

Comment: Ok sorry, i didn't watch well... So I can use the same iso from DreamSpark for all the world if I want, but I have to buy different key, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, you can use same iso file (dont have to download it over and over again, but you need new key for every new PC that you will install Windows on. I think if you remove Windows from your old PC you can install it on new one with same key.